# Flutter Custom Widget for ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make this type of ListView in flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom stateful listViewItem widget and build the listview using ListViewBuilder.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return YourWidget();
}
```

In your listview:

```
Widget buildListView() {
  ListView.builder(
    controller: _controller,
    itemCount: _itemCount,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return YourWidget(item: items[index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually main problem is to create those circles and lines.